# odoo Error: setup script specifies an absolute path

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, setup.py

i am trying to build odoo 10.0 from github and having following error running after running setup.py
error: Error: setup script specifies an absolute path:
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\babel\global.dat
On windows 7, python 2.7.9 and all requirements have been fullfilled by 
pip -r requirements.txt

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running egg_info
writing requirements to odoo.egg-info\requires.txt
writing odoo.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to odoo.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to odoo.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'odoo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.eml' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.eot' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.ico' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.jpeg' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.md' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.mp3' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.ogg' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.otf' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.pdf' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.rst' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.ttf' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.woff' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.woff2' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.wsdl' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no files found matching '*.xsd' under directory 'odoo'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory
'*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.hg*' found under directory '*
writing manifest file 'odoo.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
error: Error: setup script specifies an absolute path:
    c:\python27\lib\site-packages\babel\global.dat
setup() arguments must *always* be /-separated paths relative to the
setup.py directory, *never* absolute paths.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same error with:

```
pip install https://nightly.odoo.com/11.0/nightly/src/odoo_11.0.latest.zip
```

and I fixed it by downloading, extracting and:

commenting out in `setup.py` module (inside the odoo folder line 136)

```
include_package_data=True
```

**And replacing all the absolute paths in odoo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt with relative ones.**

Afterwards do not use:

```
pip install https://nightly.odoo.com/11.0/nightly/src/odoo_11.0.latest.zip
```

but (inside the extracted odoo directory)

```
python setup.py build
```

and/or

```
python setup.py install
```